# partially sorting an array in which some numbers are already sorted

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have to partially sort an array in descending order in which some numbers could be already sorted.

Is their any function which could do it efficiently or any efficient algorithm.

Comment: An Insertion Sort is ideal when the numbers are partially sorted.

Answer (score 7):

[**Timsort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is designed specifically for that case.

> Timsort is a hybrid sorting algorithm, derived from merge sort and
>   insertion sort, designed to perform well on many kinds of real-world
>   data. It was invented by Tim Peters in 2002 for use in the Python
>   programming language. The algorithm finds subsets of the data that are
>   already ordered, and uses the subsets to sort the data more
>   efficiently.

Another alternative is [**Smoothsort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothsort), also designed to take advantage of partially sorted data.

> It is a variation of heapsort developed by Edsger Dijkstra in 1981.
>   Like heapsort, smoothsort's upper bound is O(*n* log *n*). The
>   advantage of smoothsort is that it comes closer to O(*n*) time if the
>   input is already sorted to some degree, whereas heapsort averages
>   O(*n* log *n*) regardless of the initial sorted state.

Answer (score 0):

`std::sort` in general.

Although the exact implementation details are a quality of implementation, a good implementation of `std::sort` should take advantage of the partially sorted nature of the data. `libc++` does, for example.

Note that if you know where are the sorted pieces, you can use `std::inplace_merge`. For example, supposing that `v` is a `vector` with [1, 7) being sorted and [7, 10) being sorted too, then you can use `std::inplace_merge(v.begin() + 1, v.begin() + 7, v.begin() + 10)` however this is more error-prone.

As for the order of the result: if `<` does not suit you, feel free to provide your own comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sorting inside a loop, consider a treap or red-black tree instead.  Treaps are fast on average (but with a largish standard deviation), red-black trees give low variability in operation times (not as good on average operation time, but low operation time standard deviation).  IOW, for batch applications use a treap, for interactive applications you Might want a red-black tree so your user doesn't have to wait a long time once in a while.

If you're not sorting in a loop, then Timsort.